# Android - Removing markers when changing different maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an app that displays different tracks in a park. I have created two markers which represent the start and end of the track. I am getting a problem where when I change tracks, the marker from the previous track still shows. I tried `map.clear()` but that removed everything. I want to not show the markers from the previous track.

```
private void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .title(title)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
}

private void updateMapTrack() {
    switch (options.getTrack()) {
        case TRACK1:
            createMarker(-45.85696303760779, 170.5199563062967, "Start of track1.");
            createMarker(-45.85808344124618, 170.5247490755895, "End of track1.");
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-45.856895, 170.518673), (float) 17.8));
            break;

        case TRACK2:
            createMarker(-45.85696303760779, 170.5199563062967, "Start of track2.");
            createMarker(-45.85808344124618, 170.5247490755895, "End of track2.");
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-45.857144, 170.522713), (float) 16.32));
            break;

        case TRACK3:
            createMarker(-45.85714008365828, 170.5193834664067, "Start of track3.");
            createMarker(-45.85751258570694, 170.526808129631, "End of track3.");
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-45.858164, 170.523111), (float) 16));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep the reference to the Marker Object you created and then you have to call

`[Marker Reference].remove()` method to remove it from the GoogleMap.
for Example:

**Create Marker like this and save the reference:**

```
Marker startTrackMarker = createMarker(-45.85696303760779, 170.5199563062967, "Start of track1.");
```

**And that is how you will remove:**

```
startTrackMarker.remove()
```

**And your `createMarker` method will be changed like this:**

```
private Marker createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title) {
        return map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
    }
```

**Note:**

If you have multiple markers then you will need an array to hold all the references to the markets like this:

```
ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then to remove these markers you will have to iterate the array and call `remove()` on every marker object. (Otherwise, it all depends upon your logic).